# How to suppress PyExcel Empty Row Warning during file read to SQLAlclemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyexcel

I am saving the contents of an excel file to a SQLAlchemy DB table using pyexcel as following: `pyexcel.save_as(file_name='my_excel_file.xlsx',` 
    `name_columns_by_row=0,` 
                 `dest_session=db.session,` 
                 `dest_table=models.MyModel)`

This is working well and saving the data but it's leaving several log messages that `One empty row is found` in the terminal. How do I suppress these messages to avoid polluting the logs? I know about the empty rows and they have no impact to the data loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out pyexcel does a bit more on abstractions, the heavy lifting is done by pyexcel-io which does the basic input and output.
With this understanding, in the pyexcel docs there is a parameter `skip_empty_rows=True` for when you reading from a source file which if you pass to the `pyexcel.save_as` function and this silences the logged messages, so it was exactly what I needed in this use-case.
See [PyExcel Docs Ref for pyexcel.save_as](http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.save_as.html#pyexcel.save_as)